# Audio not working kubuntu dell xps 13 9343

Tags: sound, dell, pulseaudio, alsa

I am facing audio problems on kubuntu 14.04.

I have already removed the fast boot from  windows 8. So, That can't be the problem.

I was trying this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

paacmd shows that the device is not muted.

Here, "aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav" doesnt work for the user.

Even in the admin am getting error

```
subodh@Arya-XPS:~$ sudo -i
root@Arya-XPS:~# sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

Once I had tried this command to get the  audio working:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

now it is no longer working.

So  it is a configuration  problem on kubuntu?

Comment: When did sound problem occur, did it work when you installed Kubuntu

Comment: When i kubuntu installed it was not working. Then I read somewhere to try this : rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k. this issue  was also intermitent on windows. So i install the windows audio driver from dell support. After that it stopped working on kubuntu.

Comment: try reinstalling pulseaudio by executing following command in terminal: sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio

Comment: tried that not working

Comment: please edit your question with output of command lspci -v and content of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1413446

Answer (score 0):

**First Method:**

Execute following commands one by one in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo alsa force-reload
```

Restart your system and see if sound works.

**Second Method:**

Open the terminal and edit speech-dispatcher file by using the following command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

*and change* `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no`

Restart your system and see if it works.

**If none of above works, try editing alsa-base.conf by following method:**

Execute following commands in terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add this line to the file and save it, then reboot your system.

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

Comment: the first and third command doesnt work.

Comment: For the second command file does not exist . I have checked in other system having kubuntu. It doesnt need that file.